# How can I catch both single-click and double-click events on WPF FrameworkElement?

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, double-click

I can catch a **single-click** on a TextBlock like this:

```
private void TextBlock_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("you single-clicked");
}
```

I can catch a **double-click** on a TextBlock like this:

```
private void TextBlock_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        if (e.ClickCount == 2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("you double-clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

**But how do I catch them both on a single TextBlock and differentiate between the two?**

Comment: How will the _user_ differentiate between them?

Answer (score 13):

You need to fire the event after the click sequence is over... when is that? I suggest using a timer. The MouseDown event would reset it and increase the click count. When timer interval elapses it makes the call to evaluate the click count.

```
    private System.Timers.Timer ClickTimer;
    private int ClickCounter;

    public MyView()
    {
        ClickTimer = new Timer(300);
        ClickTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(EvaluateClicks);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TextBlock_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ClickTimer.Stop();
        ClickCounter++;
        ClickTimer.Start();
    }

    private void EvaluateClicks(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        ClickTimer.Stop();
        // Evaluate ClickCounter here
        ClickCounter = 0;
    }
```

Cheers!

Comment: @kelton52, i tried to show how it works. Use 'MouseLeftButtonDown' event or any other that fits your needs.

Comment: [This MSDN code sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WPF-multiclick-behavior-bb9ee00b) shows how to create an attached behaviour which will run a double click command if the element is clicked twice within the system double click time or a single click command if not.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to detect the difference, I suggest you use a control such as `Label` that does the work for you:

```
label.MouseDown += delegate(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ClickCount == 1)
    {
        // single click
    }
};

label.MouseDoubleClick += delegate
{
    // double click
};
```

EDIT: My advice was following from documentation on MSDN:

> The Control class defines the
>   PreviewMouseDoubleClick and
>   MouseDoubleClick events, but not
>   corresponding single-click events. To
>   see if the user has clicked the
>   control once, handle the MouseDown
>   event (or one of its counterparts) and
>   check whether the ClickCount property
>   value is 1.

However, doing so will give you a single click notification even if the user single clicks.

Comment: +1 for suggestion to use label, didn't realize it inherited from Control unlike TextBlock, but actually in my application I am receiving a FrameworkElement so I need some solution without using Control.

Comment: "However, doing so will give you a single click notification even if the user single clicks." - you mean it gives you a single click even if the user *double* clicks, right?

Comment: This doesn't work at all.  You will still get MouseDown upon a double click and e.ClickCount will equal 1.

Answer (score 2):

You must use a timer to differentiate between the two. Add a timer to your form in the GUI (easiest that way - it will automatically handle disposing etc...). In my example, the timer is called `clickTimer`.

```
private bool mSingleClick;

private void TextBlock_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        if (e.ClickCount < 2)
        {
            mSingleClick = true;
            clickTimer.Interval = System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime;
            clickTimer.Start();
        }
        else if (e.ClickCount == 2)
        {
            clickTimer.Stop();
            mSingleClick = false;
            MessageBox.Show("you double-clicked");
        }
    }
}

private void clickTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (mSingleClick)
    {
        clickTimer.Stop();
        mSingleClick = false;
        MessageBox.Show("you single-clicked");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it this Way and it works perfectly

```
If e.Clicks = 2 Then
            doubleClickTimer.Stop()
        ElseIf e.Clicks = 1 Then
            doubleClickTimer.Enabled = True
            doubleClickTimer.Interval = 1000
            doubleClickTimer.Start()


        End If


 Private Sub doubleClickTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles doubleClickTimer.Tick

        OpenWebPage("abc")
        doubleClickTimer.Stop()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are simply can use `MouseDown` event and count click number, like this:

```
if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left && e.ClickCount == 2)
{
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: Much simpler than the other answers.

Comment: ...but doesn't help, if you need to differentiate between single & double click, i.e. handle a double-click only, if it actually was one, and a single-click only, if it actually was one...

Answer (score 0):

You could do it on MouseUp instead of MouseDown. That way you can ask the `ClickCount` property for the total number of clicks, and decide what to do from that point.

Comment: ...but that doesn't help, if you need to differentiate between single & double click, i.e. handle a double-click only, if it actually was one, and a single-click only, if it actually was one...

Answer (score 0):

It's my working solution :)

```
    #region message label click --------------------------------------------------------------------------
private Timer messageLabelClickTimer = null;

private void messageLabel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  Debug.Print(e.ChangedButton.ToString() + " / Left:" + e.LeftButton.ToString() + "  Right:" + e.RightButton.ToString() + "  click: " + e.ClickCount.ToString());
  // in MouseUp (e.ClickCount == 2) don't work!!  Always 1 comes.
  // in MouseDown is set e.ClickCount succesfully  (but I don't know should I fire one clicked event or wait second click)

  if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
  {
    if (messageLabelClickTimer == null)
    {
      messageLabelClickTimer = new Timer();
      messageLabelClickTimer.Interval = 300;
      messageLabelClickTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(messageLabelClickTimer_Tick);
    }

    if (! messageLabelClickTimer.Enabled)                                                 
    { // Equal: (e.ClickCount == 1)
      messageLabelClickTimer.Start();
    }
    else  
    { // Equal: (e.ClickCount == 2)
      messageLabelClickTimer.Stop();

      var player = new SoundPlayer(ExtraResource.bip_3short);               // Double clicked signal
      player.Play();
    }
  }
}

private void messageLabelClickTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ // single-clicked
  messageLabelClickTimer.Stop();

  var player = new SoundPlayer(ExtraResource.bip_1short);                  // Single clicked signal
  player.Play();
}    
#endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was with single/double-clicking rows in a `DataGrid` in `WPF`. For some reason the `ButtonDown` events weren't firing, only the `OnMouseLeftButtonUp` event was. Anyway, I wanted to handle the single-click differently from the double-click. It looks me a little time (I'm sure the solution isn't perfect, but it appears to work) to distill the problem down until I got it down to the below. I created a `Task` which calls an `Action` and that `Action`'s target can be updated by a second click. Hope this helps someone!

```cs
private Action _clickAction;
private int _clickCount;

private void Grid_OnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Button Click Occurred");

    _clickCount++;

    if (_clickCount == 1)
    {
        _clickAction = SingleClick;
    }

    if (_clickCount > 1)
    {
        _clickAction = DoubleClick;
    }

    if (_clickCount == 1)
    {
        Task.Delay(200)
            .ContinueWith(t => _clickAction(), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())
            .ContinueWith(t => { _clickCount = 0; });
    }
}

private void DoubleGridClick()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Double Click");
}

private void SingleGridClick()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Single Click");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, implemented in a `UserControl` by simply using a `Task`:

```
private int _clickCount = 0;
protected override void OnPreviewMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    _clickCount = e.ClickCount;
}

protected override async void OnPreviewMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (_clickCount > 1)
    {
        //apparently a second mouse down event has fired => this must be the second mouse up event
        //no need to start another task
        //the first mouse up event will be handled after the task below
        return; 
    }

    await Task.Delay(500);

    if (_clickCount == 1)
    {
        //single click
    }
    else
    {
        //double (or more) click
    }
}
```

The drawback of all these solutions is, of course, that there will be a delay before actually responding to the user's action.