# wpf canvas double click

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, double-click

I am trying to fetch a double click from the user on a canvas. I am using the previewmousedown event for this, but it isn't working properly.

The function is as following:

```
    void DrawCanvas_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        /* Check if it is a double click */
        if(e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left && e.ClickCount == 2)
        {
           //do double click actions
        }
        else
        {
           //do single click actions
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

I have tried to move it to the previewmouseup function as well, but the clickcount stays on 1.

Anyone an idea why the clickcount doesn't go up?

Comment: Are you checking using break point?

Comment: Yes, but it never goes inside the if statement for double click, also without breakpoint it doesn't work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086213/how-can-i-catch-both-single-click-and-double-click-events-on-wpf-frameworkelemen

Comment: @Gerard - I just tried in small sample and works for me without any issue. Try to show message box instead of putting breakpoint.

Comment: The message box worked and due breakpoint it only said clickcount 1, then I found out the error was in my own code executed after the double click. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown Event, use MouseLeftButtonDownEvent to overcome this Problem.